# Yii не видит валидаторы

Tags: php, yii

Использую *Yii 1.1.6*.

Есть модель, унаследованная от `CFormModel`. В ней переопределён метод `set` для динамического добавления параметров (по аналогии с модулем `user`). Правила валидации создаются динамически в методе `rules`.

При рендере `activeTextField` в форме виджет не видит `required` валидатора и, соответственно, не рендерит `<span class="required">*</span>`.

Я так полагаю, что в модели не добавляются мои валидаторы.

[Ссылка на модель](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7vlslxx9s155zo/DealCategoriesParams.php?dl=0).

Comment: [Минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода должен быть в самом вопросе.

Comment: @SergiiChenakal Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы много перекрыли базовых методов Yii, что то пошло не так где-то. Код очень напоминает спагетти код. Старайтесь так много не городить. Если Вам нужно работать с разными вариантами валидаторов почитайте про использования сценариев валидации в Yii. Также не забывайте использовать `parent` когда перекрикиваете базовые методы yii. У Вашем коде видел `$_POST['DealCategoriesParams'][$param->name]`, данные с глобального массива `$_POST` нужно обрабатывать в контроллере, модели как слой должны быть независимыми от запросов клиента